# Chrome Developer Tools - Find matching Name or Id attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-app-developer-tool

When I highlight the input on the Chrome browser and then click on "Inspect Element" from right-click menu then Chrome Developer Tools will popup.

Assume in the Chrome Developer Tools, this will appear:

```
<input type="radio" name="lineType_phone" id="lineType_new" value="new">
```

When I click on the input,  the hidden div will appear. I would like to see how it was coded in JavaScript.

Is there a way to search for `name="lineType_phone"` or `id="lineType_new"` in any of JavaScript files or debug click event for this attributes/input?

Comment: "the hidden div" was just an example. I would like debug what happen when I click on input and see what the code like in javascript

Comment: you have a tab called "Event Listeners" next to the Syles and Computed tab, that lets you see what files/code is binded to certain events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for files might not solve your problem. As sometimes files are minified or events have use lots of variables which means that searching for `name="lineType_phone"` might not be helpful.

What about searching for events bound to the element?

The code below will show events bound to the element itself

```
$._data( $("#myElement")[0], "events" ); //don't forget to get the first elem of array
```

However, some events are added through delegation. That means that the event might be bound to a parent DOM element. If that's the case, try looking for events on the parent like this:

```
$._data( $("#myElement").parent()[0], "events" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to make sure its in javascript.

Some css3 properties can do the :hover {display:block} effect.

Second, in the "source" tab, click the "drawer" button on top right corner (most left one out of 3 right cornered button).
[image: as Image]
Then there is search tab in the below section, I believe you can do a "full text" search on all javascript scripts.
[image: as Image]

Answer (score 0):

When you're viewing a Javascript file in the **Source** tab you can use <kbd>Ctl-f</kbd> to search for a string. I don't think there's a way to search all the script files at once, though. You have to do each one separately.